# Why is my semaphore on a forked process not being released?

Tags: c++, posix, semaphore, unlink

I have a problem with a POSIX semaphore being used to release a forked process. The forked process is started by calling another instance of the running process after a `fork` and `exec`. Sometimes the child is being released and other times it is not.

It is a POSIX shared memory named semaphore and the weird thing is it works sometimes. I checked the other solutions out there and their solutions did not help me.

```
void init()
{
    ...
    sem_unlink(sem_name.c_str());

    if (parent_process)
    {
        sem_t* semaphore = sem_open(sem_name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
        if (SEM_FAILED == semaphore)
        {
            display_error();
        }
        sem_close(semaphore);
    }

    child_pid = fork();

    if (child_pid == -1)
    {
        display_error();
    }
    else if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        int ret = execve(program_name, args, env);
        if (ret == -1)
        {
            display_error();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // rest of code
    }
    ...
}
```

I had the child process wait to be released in another class that has this function:

```
void wait_until_released()
{
    if (!parent_process)
    {
        sem_t* semaphore = sem_open(sem_name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
        if (SEM_FAILED == semaphore)
        {
            display_error();
        }

        sem_wait(semaphore);

        sem_close(semaphore);
        sem_unlink(semaphore);            
    }
}
```

The post was done in another location in the code:

```
void release_child()
{
    sem_t* semaphore = sem_open(sem_name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0);
    if (SEM_FAILED == semaphore)
    {
        display_error();
    }

    if (sem_post(semaphore) != 0)
    {
        display_error();
    }

    sem_close(semaphore);
    sem_unlink(semaphore);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was occurring ultimately because I was calling `sem_unlink` on the POSIX semaphore before doing a wait on it in the forked process. Calling `sem_unlink` causes the semaphore to be removed when all file descriptors have called `sem_close` on the semaphore. This, in essence, prevented my child process from being able to use that instance and be released at all.

This only works sometimes because there is a base assumption that the child is already waiting to be released by the time we call `release_child`. This is not guaranteed and was the reason that this was working sometimes and not all the time. If we call `release_child` before the child has called `sem_wait` then we remove the semaphore completely and the child creates their own version of the semaphore that never gets posted to.

By moving the `unlink` call after the if statement in the first set of code, I prevented the child process from removing the semaphore before waiting on it. Also, by removing `O_CREAT` flag from the `sem_open` in the `release_child` and `wait_until_released` functions and the `sem_unlink` from the `release_child` function, I prevented the child from creating their own semaphore.

I wanted to record the behavior that I was seeing though because that was what really caused me problems. In the middle of debugging and fixing this problem I learned that if the parent creates the semaphore but doesn't close it, the child was calling the `sem_unlink` and creating it's own version with the same name. This caused me to believe that the original semaphore was still there but that the `sem_post` and/or `sem_wait` were not working.

So just be aware of your post, wait, close, and unlink calls when you are doing semaphores. Especially when it comes to forked processes!!